# Problem with Grid view usage in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, templatefield

I want to fill the `GridView` with a `HyperLink` and other two other fields.

I tried with the below approach half heartedly. It's giving errors.

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(
    @"Select 
        FileUpload.FileName AS FileName,
        FileUpload.FilePath AS PATH,
        SubjectMaster.SubjectName AS Subject,
        MemberPersonalInformation.FirstName As SharedBy 
    from FileUpload 
    INNER JOIN ContentManagement 
        ON ContentManagement.FileId=FileUpload.FileId  
    INNER JOIN MemberPersonalInformation 
        ON MemberPersonalInformation.MemberId=ContentManagement.CreatedBy 
    INNER JOIN SubjectMaster 
        ON ContentManagement.SubjectName=SubjectMaster.SubjectId  
    where 
        FileUpload.FileId in
        (
            Select FileId 
            from ContentManagement 
            where 
                ContentId in
                (
                    Select ContentId 
                    from ContentToIndividual 
                    where ShowToMemberId=@MemberId
                ) and 
                ContentManagement.ContentTypeId=@TPD and
                ContentManagement.SessionId=@SessionId
        )", conn);

      conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
        int i = 0;
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string fip = rdr["PATH"].ToString();
            GridViewRow di = GridView1.Rows[i];

                HyperLink h1 = (HyperLink)di.FindControl("Hyperlink1");
                h1.Text = rdr["FileName"].ToString();
                h1.NavigateUrl = "download.aspx?filepath=" + fip;

                di.Cells[1].Text = rdr["SharedBy"].ToString();
                di.Cells[2].Text = rdr["Subject"].ToString();

                i++;

        }
        rdr.Close();
```

Getting Error message

> Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. 
> Parameter
>   name: index

If anybody suggest me a better way to do this or correct this error please.

Comment: Is it intentional that you are trying with `1` and `2`, instead of `.Cells[0]` and `.Cells[1]`?

Comment: sorry but I think I'm printing the hyperlink in the `Cells[0]`.

Comment: @ILLUMINATI7590: Could you please specify the line where you've got the error ..

Comment: `GridViewRow di = GridView1.Rows[i];` I'm getting error here.

Comment: @ILLUMINATI7590: I believe the cause of the exception here is that the returned result set - readed by the reader - has more items than the `GridView.Rows` collection.

Comment: My result set have 4 items .But I want to print only three items in the Grid.

Answer (score 1):

`GridView.Rows` collection indexing is zero-based. You need to initialize the `i` with a *zero*.

The error occurs when the value of the `i` variable exceedds the available indexes in the `GridView.Rows` collection. So, if initializing the `i` variable with *zero* does not solve the problem, then the returned result set - readed by the reader - has more items than the `GridView.Rows` collection.

To make sure that the value of the `i` variable does not exceed the available indexes for the `GridView.Rows` collection use the following:

```
while (rdr.Read() && i < gridView.Rows.Count)
```

If what you need is adding rows to your `GridView` then use the following:

```
while (rdr.Read() && i < 3)
{
    string fip = rdr["PATH"].ToString();
    GridViewRow di = new GridViewRow();

    ....

    gridView.Rows.Add(di);        
    i++;        
}
```

Another cause might be the indexes you are using to references the items in the `GridViewRow.Cells`.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem anyways it didn't change anything.Same problem persists.

Comment: It's skipping the whole while loop now.

Comment: @ILLUMINATI7590: Do you need to add rows to your grid ??

Comment: Leave my approach.I'm getting four items and I want to print 3 of them in grid in which one is Hyperlink how to do that?

Comment: `GridViewRow di = new GridViewRow();
` This line is giving error and where are we using `i` in this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your gridview has at least three **columns**, otherwise this line will throw the exception you describe:

```
di.Cells[2].Text = rdr["SharedBy"].ToString();
```

On a different note, you need to be careful with this line:

```
 h1.NavigateUrl = "download.aspx?filepath=" + fip;
```

passing paths to the client and then back to the server is a good way to introduce security problems, be sure that download.aspx checks the filepath parameter is to a file that really should be downloadable!! :)

Comment: The OP is getting the error at the line `GridViewRow di = GridView1.Rows[i];`

Comment: Actual I'm not even getting to this line the programme is breaking at the line `GridViewRow di = GridView1.Rows[i];`

Comment: @Akram - thanks, didn't read the whole discussion thread :-/   I'll leave this here in case it's still useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Set int i = 0; and check, index start from 0 not 1

Answer (score 0):

I think your reader collection count is not matching the size of grid row count that's why it is giving "Index was out of range" check this 
Make a check

```
if(GridView1.Rows.Count  > i)
```

then after this perform which you want